# How to make IQueryable Extension for Oracle Connect By Query

Tags: c#, oracle, expression, iqueryable

I want to make IQueryable Extension for oracle connect by. So I wrote code like this:

```
 [Table(TEST_TABLE)]
 public class TestClass {
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public int?  ParentId { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Expression I want to make

```
var queryresult = ((IQueryable<TestClass>)context.Get<TestClass>())
  .ConnectBy(3, s => s.Id == s.ParentId);
```

Actual query I want to have

```
 string query = 
   @"SELECT LEVEL, 
            Id, 
            ParentId 
       FROM TEST_TABLE 
      WHERE Name ='Henry' 
        AND LEVEL < 3 START WITH PARENTID IS NULL 
 CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = PARENTID";
```

Please help me out .
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this would be much bigger project than a simple extension. You will need to implement the IQueryable/IQueryProvider interface. A good article series on thi can be found here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattwar/2008/11/18/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-series/

Comment: I went thru most of them. But I have no clue on connect by. So I posted like that. Thanks anyway